# how to change priority of css elements

Tags: css

At some point during development, I indented text to -999 without realizing it. I have no idea where I could have done this so I started to mess with the CSS of the website. I found what I was looking for but as you can see in the screenshot the first CSS is prioritized over the second. I was curious as to whether or not you can change the priority or order of that list.

[screenshot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmU1O.png)

Comment: Add an inline-style CSS to the button. It has more priority than any other kind of CSS

Comment: Adding `!important` to the style will make the style the most important but should be used sparingly

Comment: `text-indent: 0 !important` will prioritize it above all non !important rules

Answer (score 1):

To change the priority of a CSS element, you have to add `!important`. In this case, add `text-indent: 0 !important;`

The `!important` property in CSS means that all subsequent rules on an element are to be ignored, and the rule denoted by `!important` is to be applied. This rule overrides all previous styling rules ​-- the `!important` property increases its priority.